# Rails "/api/auth/sign_in" 404 error on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want use mount_devise_token_auth_for to implement user authorization via api.

when I call http://localhost:3000/api/auth/sign_in in development mode, it works well. However, it's not working on the production server, when the url is: http://www.mywebsiteaddress.com/api/auth/sign_in. The response from the production server is "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I check the production.log in the AWS EC2 where the website being deployed, this is the error message

```
D, [2017-11-24T20:37:03.729410 #22965] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:14.914903 #23467]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 172.218.118.129 at 2017-11-24 20:37:14 +0000
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:14.970919 #23467]  INFO -- : Processing by StaticPagesController#landing as HTML
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:15.020589 #23467]  INFO -- :   Rendered static_pages/landing.html.erb within layouts/application (41.2ms)
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:15.024040 #23467]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:15.024283 #23467]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 47.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2017-11-24T20:37:53.618896 #23467]  INFO -- : Started OPTIONS "/api/auth/sign_in" for 172.218.118.129 at 2017-11-24 20:37:53 +0000
F, [2017-11-24T20:37:53.621125 #23467] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/api/auth/sign_in"):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

this is my routes config:

routes.rb

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do #namespace for the controller is :v1
        mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
        resources :tour_types, only:[:index, :show]
        resources :routes, only: [:show]
        resources :cruises, only: [:index, :show]
        post "inquiry/cruiseinquirycreate" => 'contacts_api#cruise_inquiry_create'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that production server does not allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), so I added Gem rack-cors and set up the related config and now it's working.